# Program won't stop running even with break added

Tags: c++

My code continuously runs after I choose p for class summary. It just infinitely prints the class summary over and over. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I have the break clause included, so shouldn't it break after it's done printing, even though I have it set to be a while loop?

```
    bool loop = true; 
    while(loop) { 
    switch(selection) { 
       case 'a': 
       cout << "Please enter student (First Last Grade) info:"; 
       cin >> first_name >> last_name >> grade; 
       full_name = first_name + " " + last_name; 
       names.push_back(full_name); 
       grades.push_back(grade); 
       cout << "selection:" << endl; 
       cin >> selection;
       break; 
       
       case 'r': 
       cout << "Please enter student (First Last Grade) info:"; 
       cin >> first_name >> last_name >> grade; 
       full_name = first_name + " " + last_name; 
       for (j = 0; j < names.size(); ++j) { 
          if (names.at(j) == full_name) { 
             names.erase(names.begin()+j);
          }  
       }
       for (j = 0; j <= grades.size(); ++j) { 
          if (grades.at(j) == grade) { 
             grades.erase(grades.begin()+j); 
       }
       break;
       case 'p': 
       cout << "Class Summary" << endl; 
       cout << "------------------------" << endl; 
       cout << "Name" << setw(20) << "Grade" << endl;
       cout << "---------" << setw(18) << "--------" << endl; 
       for (j = 0; j < names.size(); ++j) { 
          cout << names.at(j) << setw(12) << grades.at(j) << endl;
          average += grades.at(j);
       }
       cout << "Number of Students:" << endl;
       cout << "-------------------" << endl; 
       avgGrade = average/names.size(); 
       cout << "Average Grade:" << endl;
       cout << "--------------" << endl;
       cout << avgGrade << endl; 
       
       break;
    }
    }
    }
       
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your pasted only part of your code. What is happening before loop is entered? How selection variable is being initialized?

Comment: All of the `break`s I see are only sufficient to exit the `switch` statement. A better code example is necessary to help you fix the problem, but I'll typically solve a problem like this my moving the loop into a function so that I can return from the function to exit the loop.

Comment: Note that infinite loops are actually undefined behaviour in C++.

Comment: @MateuszDrost it wouldn't let me add anymore code than this. selection is initialized as char selection;

Comment: If you cant paste more code then maybe keep removing unnecessary code as long as bug still occurs to achieve https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The break statement in the switch statement will only break out of the switch statement, not the loop. You have to add a break statement *outside* of the loop.

Comment: Asker is expecting the `break` statements to kick them out of the loop. The bug is the `break`s are inside a `switch` and break only the the `switch`.

Comment: @user4581301 I agree. Is that not what I said? I said "The break statement in the switch statement will only break out of the switch statement, not the loop."

Comment: Apologies. I must have terribly misread your answer on my first read.

Comment: I would leave out the bit about `loop`. I think that's where my read went wrong. `loop` being unchanging is a bit silly (`while(true)` is easier on the brain), but not relevant to the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Will edit. Apology accepted.

Comment: To break the `while(loop)` he must set `loop = false;`